# Managing multiple return types in Golang

Tags: go

I'm a bit new to Go and I'm having trouble converting a response object from an API call into different structures based on the request type

Essentially, I have one func which sends out a request

```
func (fpc *FPClient) request(path string, method string, params interface{}, Token string, response interface{}) *dto.AppError {
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 15,
    }
    requestBody, err := json.Marshal(params)
    if err != nil {
         //
    }

    req, _ := http.NewRequest(method, path, bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Cookie", fmt.Sprintf("cookie=%s;", Token))
    req.SetBasicAuth(fpc.username, fpc.password)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        // 
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
       //
    }
    if FPErr := fpc.processErrors(resp, body); FPerr != nil {
        return FPErr
    }

    responseData := FPApiSuccess{Head: response, Body: response}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &responseData); err != nil {
       //
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n\n client Response : \n %+v \n", responseData.Body)
    return nil
}
```

The struct for `FPApiSuccess` is:

```
type FPApiSuccess struct {
    Body interface{} `json:"body"`
    Head interface{} `json:"head"`
}
```

Right now, there are 2 calling functions and the API response expected is a bit different for both

Both API responses have the below structure

```
{
    "head": {},
    "body": {}
}
```

However, the nested details in each key is different based on the API used.

I want to capture the `head` and `body` keys in a struct argument I give and send it back to the calling function. The `response` argument in the `request` function is a different struct type based on the calling function.

I'm unable to get this to work - I'm only getting back a blank struct from the `request` function. This is the `fmt.PrintF` log

```
 client Response : 
 &{Body:{BOrderID:0 CC: Exch: EOID: Type: Local:0 Message: } Head:{ResponseCode: Status: StatusDescription:}}
```

This is an empty struct - ideally, it should be populated with the values retrieved from the API.

For reference, heres the struct passed as an argument as `response` in the request function:

```
   type FPApiResponse struct {
        Body FPBodyResponse `json:"body"`
        Head FPHeadResponse `json:"head"`
    }

    type FPHeadResponse struct {
        ResponseCode      string `json:"responseCode"`
        Status            string `json:"status"`
        StatusDescription string `json:"statusDescription"`
    }

    type FPBodyResponse struct {
        BOrderID   int    `json:"BOrderID"`
        CC      string `json:"CC"`
        Exch            string `json:"Exch"`
        EOID     string `json:"EOID"`
        Type        string `json:"Type"`
        Local    int    `json:"Local"`
        Message         string `json:"Message"`
    }
```

### Update

So I did this; instead of

```
responseData := FPApiSuccess{Head: response, Body: response}
```

I did this

```
responseData := fivePaisaApiSuccess{}
```

So now, I get the below in console

```
 Client Response : 
 {Body:map[BOrderID:0 CC:52715111 Type:D Local:0 Message:Invalid Session ] Head:map[responseCode:5POrdReq status:0 statusDescription:Success]}
```

So essentially, this works, but the calling function doesn't seem to get the proper response:

Here's the calling function

```
func (fpc *FPClient) PlaceOrder(orderParams dto.OrderBodyParams, variety string, Token string) (string, *dto.AppError) {
    var result FPApiResponse

    headParams := dto.FFPOrderHeadParams{
      //
    }
    FPOrderParams := dto.FPOrderParams{
       //
    }
    FPErr := fpc.request(FPURL+FPPlaceOrder, http.MethodPost, FPOrderParams, brokerAccessToken, &result)
    if FPErr != nil {
        return "", FPErr
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n\n Client result : \n %+v \n", result)
    if result.Head.Status != "0" {
       //
    }

    if result.Body.Status != 0 {
      //
    }
    return strconv.Itoa(result.Body.Broker), nil
}
```

The `result` value is blank:

```
 {Body:{BOId:0 CC: Exch: Type: Local:0 Message: Status:0} Head:{ResponseCode: Status: StatusDescription:}}
```

I don't understand, this pointer is getting populated in the request function

Here's the struct I'm passing to the request:

```
type FPApiResponse struct {
    Body FPBodyResponse `json:"body"`
    Head FPHeadResponse `json:"head"`
}
```

Comment: You're setting the `FPApiResponse` value as the `Body` and `Head` of the `FPApiSuccess` value. Both of those two structs expect a head+body json object. So for it to unmarshal into these values the json you receive would have to actually be a nested version of the one you're expecting, ie https://play.golang.com/p/J7kmSEspguO

Comment: @mkopriva - you're right , i split the structs into 2 (head and body) and sending them both like so `responseData := FPApiSuccess{Head: headResponse, Body: bodyResponse}` - this seemed to do the trick

Comment: @Kannaj: Just a tip, given that you're new to golang: avoid using the `interface{}` type too much. Consider it a necessary evil, if nothing else. `interface{}` is good for some things, but the moment you _know_ what data you're dealing with, use a specific type instead

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - understood , thank you. I can already forsee the pain it would cause :)